# Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? Exception

Tags: java, https

I have a java complied package to speak with the https server on net. Running the compilation gives the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
```

I think this is due to the connection established with the client machine is not secure.  Is there any way to configure the local machine or ports in order to connect to the remote https server?

Comment: For the sake of Google search this is recently being returned as "Unrecognized record version TLS-0.0 , plaintext connection?"

Answer (score 314, accepted):

> I think this is due to the connection
>   established with the client machine is
>   not secure.

It is due to the fact that you are talking to an HTTP server, not an HTTPS server. Probably you didn't use the correct port number for HTTPS.

Comment: I have the same error, and I solved when I started using http instead of https. But when I place the link in browser with https it works! And I need to perform a safe query. Any idea on how can I solve the problem?

Comment: @rsy When you 'placed the link ... with https' the browser would have changed to port 443 for you. You can do the same yourself. Indeed `HttpURLConnection` will automatically do it for you, if you don't specify a port at all.

Comment: I assume that you can setup any port on your server to be HTTPS, it doesn't have to be a specific port?

Comment: @KarlSherwin It can be any port you like, subject to reservations, but if it isn't 443 you will have to cart that around yourself in all your URLs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I was using port 80 for an HTTPS connection. When I changed it to 443 it worked as expected.

Comment: @VipulVerma You were exporting a plaintext HTTP service on port 80 and trying to use it as though it was an HTTPS service, which it wasn't.

Comment: I was using skprapeit, and that was the problem. I had to add the `443` port at the HTTPs request

Comment: @polendina Same as all the others.

Answer (score 22):

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

You should have a local SMTP domain name that will contact the mail server and establishes a new connection as well you should change the SSL property in your programming below

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection

 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true"); // Should be true
```

Comment: He is speaking HTTPS, not SMTP. -1

Comment: In my case that worked, thanks! javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.livemusicgo.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Comment: @surfealokesea The question is about HTTP and HTTPS, and an answer or a personal experience about SMTP isn't relevant.

Comment: Yes but this is not just for him it is for other users that are having this same 'unrecognized ssl message'. +1 to you, Thobith

Comment: I also Had "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?"  Error and this worked out for me. In my case it was SMTP

Answer (score 12):

I got the same error message when I forgot to log in to the company firewall, before performing a POST request through a proxy.

Comment: I had to do the same although I was inside the company !

Comment: can you please explain in brief how to resolve, me too facing same issue in my company right ow

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error. it was because I was accessing the https port using http.. The issue solved when I changed http to https.

Comment: No, you got the error when accessing the HTTP port via HTTPS. Read the error message. You connected to a plaintext target. The situation you described wouldn't have caused an SSLException, as you wouldn't have been using SSL.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this as an answer as it might help someone later.

I had to force jvm to use the IPv4 stack to resolve the error. My application used to work within company network, but while connecting from home it gave the same exception. No proxy involved. Added the jvm argument 
   `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` and all the `https` requests were behaving normally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running local using spring i'd suggest use:

```
@Bean
public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() throws IOException {
    return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(
                    new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                            new BasicAWSCredentials("fake", "credencial")
                    )
            )
            .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfigurationFactory().getConfig().withProtocol(Protocol.HTTP))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("localhost:8443", "central"))
            .build();
}
```

It works for me using unit test.

Hope it's help!

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue from Java application built in Jdevelopr 11.1.1.7 IDE. I solved the issue by unchecking the use of proxy form Project properties.

You can find it in the following:
Project Properties -> (from left panle )Run/Debug/Profile ->Click (edit) form the right panel -> Tool Setting from the left panel -> uncheck (Use Proxy) option.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem using port 25 and Following prop

```
mailSender.javaMailProperties.putAll([
                "mail.smtp.auth": "true",
                "mail.smtp.starttls.enable": "false",
                "mail.smtp.ssl.enable": "false",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback": "true",
        ]);
```

Comment: earlier you used smtps then as a temporary workaround you fallback to smtp. These errors are related to https/smtps.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use Jetty version 9 or earlier you need to add it to jetty
by

```
RUN java -jar ${JETTY_HOME}/start.jar --add-to-startd=https
```

and according to this
[Jetty: How to use SSL in Jetty client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146476/jetty-how-to-use-ssl-in-jetty-client-side)

from Jetty version 10 it should work out of the box

Answer (score -1):

if connection is FTPS test:

FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient(protocol, false);

protocol = TLS,SSL
and false = isImplicit.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing this exception when using Gmail.

In order to use Gmail I had to **turn ON "Allow less secure apps"**.

This Gmail setting can be found at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps after login the gmail account.

Answer (score -1):

I've got similar error using camel-mail component to send e-mails by gmail smtp.

The solution was changing from TLS port (587) to SSL port (465) as below:

```
<route id="sendMail">
  <from uri="jason:toEmail"/>
  <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
  <setHeader headerName="Subject"><constant>Something</constant></setHeader>
  <to uri="smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465?username=myemail@gmail.com&amp;password=mypw&amp;to=someemail@gmail.com&amp;debugMode=true&amp;mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"/>
</route>
```

Comment: No, the solution was changing to a *plaintext* port.