# Jetty: How to use SSL in Jetty client side

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I am using Jetty to develop my client application side.
I am not using Jetty in the server part.
What I need to configure on the client side to be able send "https" request using the Jetty client?

That is what I do for HTTP client:

```
httpClient = new HttpClient();
// Configure HttpClient
httpClient.setFollowRedirects(false);

httpClient.start();

Request request = httpClient.newRequest(url);
//code
httpClient.stop();
```

I got this exception if I try to send request using "https":

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.getResult(FutureResponseListener.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.get(FutureResponseListener.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:653)
    at egm.httpClient.jetty.TestBackend.POST(TestBackend.java:204)
    at egm.httpClient.jetty.TestStep.execute(TestStep.java:77)
    at egm.httpClient.jetty.TestSuite.execute(TestSuite.java:57)
    at egm.httpClient.jetty.TestLauncher.main(TestLauncher.java:139)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslClientConnectionFactory.newConnection(SslClientConnectionFactory.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractHttpClientTransport$ClientSelectorManager.newConnection(AbstractHttpClientTransport.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(ManagedSelector.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1600(ManagedSelector.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run(ManagedSelector.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.execute(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.run(ManagedSelector.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since jetty-client >= 10

[HttpClient supports HTTPS requests out-of-the-box like a browser does.](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-10/programming-guide/index.html#pg-client-http-configuration-tls)

---

Prior jetty-client 9

[In order to perform HTTPS requests, you should create first a SslContextFactory.Client](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20perform%20HTTPS%20requests%2C%20you%20should%20create%20first%20a%20SslContextFactory.Client)

You have to pass a `SslContextFactory` into the `HttpClient` like this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new SslContextFactory());
```

You can even configure the `SslContextFactory` by trusting all or give it a keystore:

```
new SslContextFactory(true);
new SslContextFactory("/path/to/.keystore");
```

Answer (score 5):

this is what worked for me with jetty-11

```
SslContextFactory.Client sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Client();
sslContextFactory.setTrustAll(true); // you might want to think about this first


ClientConnector clientConnector = new ClientConnector();
clientConnector.setSslContextFactory(sslContextFactory);

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientTransportDynamic(clientConnector));
httpClient.start();
```

for explanation, check out the official documentation here https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/programming-guide/index.html#pg-client-http-configuration-tls