# Unable to Send Mail - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, jakarta-mail

We are sending Mail using Spring **JavaMailSenderImpl**. Following is the configuration

```xml
 <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${mail.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${mail.password}"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <!-- Use SMTP transport protocol -->
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol" >${mail.transport.protocol}</prop>
                <!-- Use SMTP-AUTH to authenticate to SMTP server -->
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">${mail.smtp.auth}</prop>
                <!-- Use TLS to encrypt communication with SMTP server -->
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">${mail.smtp.starttls.enable}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**Properties File :-**

```
host=XXXX.XXXX.XX
port=25
mail.username=xxxxxxxx
mail.password=xxxxxxx
mail.transport.protocol=smtp
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

**Console Logs**

```
Exception in thread "taskExecutor-2" org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: XXXX.XXXX.XX, port: 25;
      nested exception is:
            javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: XXXX.XXXX.XX, port: 25;
      nested exception is:
            javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?; message exception details (1) are:
    Failed message 1:
    javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: XXXX.XXXX.XX, port: 25;
      nested exception is:
            javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
            at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:389)
            at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
            at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:336)
            at com.XXXX.Mailer$1.run(Mailer.java:52)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
            at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)
            at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:507)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
            ... 9 more
```

We are convinced that this is not related to the SSL certificate as there are other web applications deployed in the same server which sends email perfectly with the same configuration. What could be the issue here ?

Comment: Are you sure that config is correct? The SMTP SSL port is usually not 25 and more like 465

Comment: Positive.  Different applications in the same server has the same config and can send email.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question, because the linked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception talks about HTTPs vs. HTTP and *NOT* about SMTPS vs. SMTP like the OP here

Comment: @StefanHaberl IMO the underlying reason is likely similar -- this error is not specific to the HTTP/SMTP protocol, but to the SSL protocol which both HTTPS and SMTPS share.

Comment: @OctaviaTogami yes, it's the same reason. However, you have to set different properties for HTTP and SMTP to get this to work

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
<prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">${mail.smtp.starttls.enable}</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.enable">true</prop>
```

You want either `mail.smtp.ssl.enable` for implicit SSL directly after TCP connect (port 465) or `mail.smtp.starttls.enable` for explicit SSL using the STARTTLS command (port 25). But with your current properties you set both to true.

This means it will do a TCP connect to port 25 and try a SSL handshake there. This will fail because the server is sending a plain text greeting from the SMTP dialog and not the expected SSL handshake. Thus you get

> Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

To fix it make sure that you either use implicit or explicit SSL but not both depending on the port, i.e. for port 25 `mail.smtp.ssl.enable` should be false.

Comment: I will try this. But what is confusing is that we have enabled both to true in a different application in the same tomcat server and the mail just works fine. Is there anything here that could make it specific to a deployed application in tomcat ?

Comment: @ArunM: My guess is that it will not try explicit TLS (STARTTLS) if implicit TLS is already done because it does not make sense to do TLS inside TLS. This means that `mail.smtp.starttls.enable` will be implicitly ignored if `mail.smtp.ssl.enable` is true and thus any connections with port 465 (smtps) should just work.

Answer (score 2):

As of 02/Nov/2023, the following values are working when sending emails through Amazon ses:

```
mail.host=email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
mail.user=****
mail.user.password=***
mail.from=abc@whatever.com

mail.debug=false

mail.smtp.timeout=60000
mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=60000
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.transport.protocol=smtps
mail.smtp.host=email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
mail.smtp.port=587
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true


#JUST REMOVE THE FOLLOWING PROPERTIES 
#mail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2
#mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtpserver
#mail.transport.protocol.rfc822=smtps
#mail.smtp.user=***
#mail.smtp.password=***
#mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=587
#mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.SocketFactory
#mail.smtps.auth=true
#mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs in javax.mail 1.4.0, upgrading to 1.4.7 fixes the issue in my case

Answer (score 0):

I tried to resolve this by many methods but finally found this working by myself.

1. Make sure you are able to send emails from Terminal or by any other mail client before creating code. Once your have tested mail is working fine then use below properties and code. I have deployed the Code in the Email server so I don't require SSL or TLS. I am using port 25 for Relay.
2. Required Properties -

   ```
   mail.smtp.host=<myhostname.com>
   mail.smtp.port=25
   mail.smtp.auth=true
   mail.transport.protocol=smtp
   smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated
   user=<sender_username/email>
   password=<password>
   mail.smtp.username=<sender_username/email>
   mail.smtp.password=<password>
   ```
3. Required Code -

   ```
   public String sendEmail(String email){

            //Compose the message  
             try {  

                   FileReader reader=new FileReader("smtp.properties");  
                //Get the session object  
                   Properties props = new Properties(); 
                   props.load(reader); 

                   System.out.println(" Props :: " + props.toString());
                   String to = email;
                   String host=props.getProperty("mail.smtp.host");
                   final String user=props.getProperty("user");
                   final String password=props.getProperty("password");

                  Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                   new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                           return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
                       }
                   }); 

                   Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                   message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
                   message.setRecipients(
                           Message.RecipientType.TO,
                           InternetAddress.parse(to)
                   );

                   message.setSubject("Testing - SMTP");
                   message.setText("Dear User, \n\n Hello !");

                   Transport.send(message);

                   System.out.println("Done");

                  } catch (MessagingException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException ex) {  
                       ex.printStackTrace();
                  }
             return "SUCCESS";
        }
   ```
4. Required Imports -

   ```
   import javax.mail.*;
   import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
   import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
   import java.util.Properties;
   ```