# Unable to read Email using IMAP in JAVA.

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, imap

I am trying to read email from Mail Server using JAVA. I've used IMAP protocol for that.

Everytime when I send request to read an email it throws me exception saying: *javax.mail.MessagingException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?*

Here's my Code;

```
public void readEmail() throws Exception {
    sessionIMAP = setupImap();
    Store store = sessionIMAP.getStore("imap");
    store.connect("localhost", 1143, "username", "password");
    if (store.isConnected()) {
        System.out.println("IMAP is connected");
    } else {
        System.out.println("IMAP is not connected");
    }

}

private Session setupImap() {
    System.out.println("in setupImap");
    Session session1;
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
    //props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
    //props.put("mail.imaps.auth", "true");
    //props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");
    props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.put("mail.imap.host", "localhost");
    props.put("mail.imap.port", 1143);
    props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", 1143);
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    //props.put("mail.imaps.class", "com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore");
    session1 = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    //setupIMAPMsgTypeSetupForReportedIssue();
    return session1;
}
```

Here's the full Exception I am getting:

```
    DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.6
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 1143, isSSL false
Invalid Args: read_Email
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.thalesifec.framework.tool.support.FwkAnnotatedTools$FwkToolClassInfo.execute(FwkAnnotatedTools.java:103)
    at com.thalesifec.framework.tool.support.interactive.ConsoleInterface.handleToolSelected(ConsoleInterface.java:217)
    at com.thalesifec.framework.tool.support.interactive.ConsoleInterface.interactiveCommandLoop(ConsoleInterface.java:113)
    at com.thalesifec.framework.tool.support.interactive.ConsoleInterface.noArgsStart(ConsoleInterface.java:271)
    at com.thalesifec.framework.tool.support.interactive.ConsoleInterface.delegateCommand(ConsoleInterface.java:295)
    at com.thalesifec.framework.connectivitymanager.simulator.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:670)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at com.thalesifec.framework.connectivitymanager.simulator.plugins.EMBATLTestTool.readEmail(EMBATLTestTool.java:136)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:354)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:211)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:116)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:115)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:685)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:636)
    ... 12 more
```

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590597/unable-to-send-mail-javax-net-ssl-sslexception-unrecognized-ssl-message-plai

Comment: You're running a local IMAP server, and you haven't configured it to use SSL (the server).

Comment: While you're fixing things, [get rid of all that socket factory stuff](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), and [upgrade to a newer version of JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out below line from the code and it worked!

```
props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

Thank You