# grails : Could not connect to SMTP host: *********, port: 25

Tags: java, email, grails

Can anyone help me with this, I was unable to send email from my app and experiencing below errors.

Logs:

```
Could not connect to SMTP host: ****.******.** port: 25;

nested exception is:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.webbfontaine.ci, port: 25;
  nested exception is:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: 
Could not connect to SMTP host: ****.******.**, port: 25;
  nested exception is:


javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1986)

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:656)

at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)

at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:486)

at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:406)

at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345)

at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
```

Here is my grails config:

```
 grails{
        mail {
            disabled = false
            host = "*****.****.**"
            port = 25
            username = "account"
            password=""
            props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"false",
                     "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"25"]
        }
    }
```

Build COnfig:

```
compile ":mail:1.0.7"
```

Hoping for your generous help.

Thanks

Comment: can you telnet to *****.****.** 25  so telnet host 25 from the host that is attempting to send msg - by the way the host is showing in the actual error message above Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.web.......If you don't have telnet you can use nmapnmap -sS -O -p 25 {hostname}

Comment: @Romz have you tried port number "587" ?

Comment: @vahid, i did telnet it and got this....

220 mail01.net.******.** ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4; Wed, 21 Sep 2016 04:17:18 GMT
500 5.5.1 Command unrecognized: ""

Comment: Usually telnet to the port will open connection on port 25 and await a prompt. As someone has suggested you are attempting to initialise SSL and this appears to be on a non ssl port. So possibly look up configuration for basic port 25 connection (Disabling ssl config) or verify you have smtp on ssl at your end and configure accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The error message also points to an SSL connection.  Seems like you are trying to connect to an SSL port using standard SMTP TCP.  Here is a Stack Over flow that has a similar error message.

[unrecognized ssl message plaintext connection exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use correct SSL port number. By default SSL/TLS encrypted SMTP uses port 465.