# Sending mail using java mail API but getting error. i can do successful. suggest bug fixing or provide correct code

Tags: java

Code:

```
import java.util.*;  
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendEmail  
{  
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String host="chnmail.hcl.com";
    final String user="allwinjayson.m@hcl.com";
    final String password="*********";
    String to="allwinjayson.m@hcl.com";

    //Get the session object  
    Properties props = new Properties();  
    props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);  
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");


    //new
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
    {  
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
            {  
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
            }  
    });  


     //Compose the message  
    try 
    {  
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Testing");
        message.setText("This is simple program of sending email using JavaMail API");

        //send the message  
         Transport.send(message);  
         System.out.println("message sent successfully...");  
    } 
    catch (MessagingException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
}
```

**Error:**

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: chnmail.hcl.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
    at SendingClass.SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:55)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:694)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:503)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:234)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the socket factory and it will work. SMTP over port 25 will initially be plaintext, and the `starttls` will then negotiate TLS for encryption.

Note that you will need JavaMail 1.4.5 or higher for this ([current latest](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.sun.mail%22%20AND%20a%3A%22javax.mail%22) is 1.5.6).