# weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: Exception occurred during SSLEngine.unwrap

Tags: ssl, weblogic11g, oraclereports, wallet, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am trying to connect to WLS Report server from OHS server which contains a wallet. when I try to connect I got below exception. I have tried with out SSL and it Works.

- List item

I have enabled below Cipher Suites.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC6qh.png)

```
<BEA-000000> <[Thread[ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer',5,Thread Group for Queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer']]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: Exception occurred during SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]).
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.EngineInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(EngineInputRecord.java:152)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:806)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:721)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:647)
    at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine$5.run(JaSSLEngine.java:134)
    at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doAction(JaSSLEngine.java:732)
    at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.unwrap(JaSSLEngine.java:132)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrap(JSSEFilterImpl.java:505)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrapAndHandleResults(JSSEFilterImpl.java:448)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:80)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:64)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.isMessageComplete(JSSEFilterImpl.java:282)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:962)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocket(SocketMuxer.java:899)
    at weblogic.socket.PosixSocketMuxer.processSockets(PosixSocketMuxer.java:130)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)
> 
####<Mar 10, 2017 9:07:40 AM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <csd-wls1-182> <WLS_REPORTS> <ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <744e6fca194406a7:42d925d8:15ab2b89006:-8000-000000000000001d> <1489117060113> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer',5,Thread Group for Queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer']]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.closeOutbound(): value=closed.> 
####<Mar 10, 2017 9:07:40 AM IST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <csd-wls1-182> <WLS_REPORTS> <ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <744e6fca194406a7:42d925d8:15ab2b89006:-8000-000000000000001d> <1489117060113> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer',5,Thread Group for Queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer']]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = CLOSED HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 7.>
```

Comment: I use jdk1.6.0_37 as my java

Comment: please format it.. it is very hard to understand logs and your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception)

Answer (score 0):

The connection URL to weblogic must be `https://` instead of `http://`