# Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection in postman

Tags: ssl, curl, google-apps, postman, rest-client

I'm making a GET call in postman getting

```
{
  "message": "Unknown Exception",
  "error": "Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?"
}
```

But when I do the same GET call from my terminal by converting the same request to curl, it works well. What exactly going wrong?

No issues if I use FireFox RestClient. The only problem is with google's postman.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception)

Comment: @EJP, I'm getting this error only in post-man. If I make the same call using curl command, it's working without any issues.