# Gradle sync failed: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to build my gradle but it fails to build and diplays the following message in Android Studio

> Gradle sync failed: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
>   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

The following message is shown on Android Monitor

> Please configure Android SDK

Once I configure Android SDK it shows the following:-

[image: Project Structure]

Once I fill this out the error changes to :

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find method android() for arguments
>   [build_5xge73exnwldgwxfnjosseesw$_run_closure3@45218b07] on root
>   project 'MyApplication' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>                 Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

build.gradle is as shown :

> // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
>
> buildscript {
>       repositories {
>           jcenter()
>       }
>       dependencies {
>           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
>
> ```
>     // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
>     // in the individual module build.gradle files
> } }
> ```
>
> allprojects {
>       repositories {
>           jcenter()
>       } }
>
> task clean(type: Delete) {
>       delete rootProject.buildDir }

Comment: Hi ! Please add your gradle file

Comment: hey i think you will find your solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception

Comment: Delete this part `task clean(type: Delete) { delete rootProject.buildDir }` and see what happens.

Comment: @ND1010_ Sorry but that didn't helped me it is term for Java and that too for client and server related query but my problem is i couldn't even build a new project it shows this error every time

Comment: @MehranZamani That deleting that didn't work

Comment: @Cyborg You should have `android` block in your `build.gradle` of your app(not project). Something like `android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias '**'
            keyPassword '**'
            storeFile file('**')
            storePassword '**'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion **
    buildToolsVersion "**"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "**"
        minSdkVersion **
        targetSdkVersion **
        versionCode **
        versionName "**"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}` which seems to be missing.

Comment: Thank you for your help @MehranZamani . I just reinstalled everything and the error was removed. Don't know the reason.

Comment: My guess was that you delete some part of `build.gradle`. Check it out to be sure next time ;)