# JMeter recording use non http/https protocol

Tags: jmeter

I am recording our game app using JMeter

And it has an API server, which using the WebSocket's protocol

While meeting that request sent to API server, I always get this message, and can't go further

[image]

Is that means I need to modify the original JMeter's source code to walk around this problem? Or any way out? If so, that'd be appreciated.

Comment: you should use HTTPS and not HTTP, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to record and replay WebSocket transport using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is a different beast, given you have a game application my expectation is that it might be the case application opens a WebSocket connection and re-uses it until the end of session and so you won't be able to mimic this behavior using "normal" [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers as WebSocket assumes either `ws` or `wss` protocol.

I would suggest considering one of the following JMeter Plugins:

- [WebSocket Sampler by Maciej Zaleski](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler/wiki)
- [WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/overview)

Both plugins can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager):

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager WebSocket]