# I use the code but ender up with the errorjavax.mail.MessagingException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?;

Tags: jakarta-mail

```
Mailer(String protocolType, String host, Integer port, String username, String password) throws Exception {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;

    this.props = new Properties();
    this.props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", protocolType);



    this.session = Session.getInstance(props);

    store = session.getStore();
    store.connect(host, port, username, password);
}

Mailer mailer = null;
    try {
        mailer = new Mailer("imaps", "smtp.gmail.com", 587, "hsdvyfgyfg@gmail.com", "ghghghfgf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mailer.setSMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, true);
```

Comment: This link will be usefull for what you are trying. https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/ . Looks like the configuration imaps and smtp.gmail.com is not  correct.

Comment: See the [Gmail instructions in the JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception)