# Apache Axis 1.4: Calling a SOAP API on an https server through an http proxy

Tags: ssl, soap, proxy, axis, tls1.2

The problem is as follows:

- We have a SOAP API running behind TLS1.2 and SNI
- Our main software is stuck on JDK6 where it is basically impossible to connect to a server using SNI
- We need to use Axis 1.4 for SOAP calls
- We have set up a simple Apache Proxy rerouting calls to `http://proxyIP/foo` to `https://mainIP/`

The proxy works like a charm when tested manually or in a browser.
However, using Axis to do the required SOAP calls fails with an Exception:

```
Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

What could cause this and how could we fix this?

Every idea is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception)

Comment: @RafałCzabaj I've seen that one and it's a far too general situation, sadly. Simple ports are not the issue here.

Comment: Can you also try to communicate on Https -> Https instead Http-> Https ? It might be that there is some cache setting in between, that is not cleared out.