# Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

This is just a demo project downloaded from : https://start.spring.io/

I am very new to this and don't know how to proceed

The Build error that I am getting.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.4.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.4.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\U660221\Downloads\demo\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.4.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: do you have a parent module/project with that artifact/groupId and version?

Comment: have you configured your settings.xml to add the correct repositories?

Comment: `Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM` ==> maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception) will help.

Comment: @Stultuske yes it was related to settings.xml . Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a  tag in your POM like this :

```
   <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
   </parent>
```