# spring boot feign client: why ssl error when it is a http call

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

spring-boot version: 1.5.21.RELEASE

both the service provider and the service caller are the same spring boot version.

What I want to know is that why it is an SSL error when it is calling a http serivce?

below is part of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: feign.RetryableException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? executing PUT http://serivce-name/service/api
    at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:67)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:104)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:108)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at feign.Client$Default.convertAndSend(Client.java:133)
    at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:73)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception)

Comment: I don't think so. According to the message in feign.RetryableException, the feign client is querying an HTTP service, which should not get SSL involved. I think that might be something wrong with the feign client or some configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I'm using `eureka` for `discovery server` and `feign client` to conect between services. My problem was in then services' eureka configuration.

The source service was configured to use only `http` protocol:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    secure-port-enabled: false
    non-secure-port-enabled: true
```

The target service was configured to use `https` protocol:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    secure-port-enabled: true
    non-secure-port-enabled: false
```

In this configuration, the source server was trying to conect to target server via `http` protocol, but the target was configured with `https`.

So, I changed the target configuration like the source and It worked!